# Change string.xml of default apps

Tags: android, string

I want to change some labels of the phones default apps.
For example, I want to change the "Clear" button of the Calculator to "Delete". I have tried to change string.xml in the phone drive in "strings\packages\apps\Calculator\res". In this directory there are folders according to the phones language.
I have tried changing every string.xml file in there, but the label did not changed!

I saw these folders also exists on the sd card. I also tried changing there. It didn't help either.

Can anybody please help me and tell me how can I change labels\buttons\text that supposed to be on the string.xml?

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to just change the strings.xml file, you need to compile the code of the app you're trying to change. You need the complete application source to change the strings and then to build it. Then you can uninstall the app on your phone and install the changed version. You can get Android built-in applications sources online, for example, here's the link to the calculator app you've mentioned.

[Android RPN Calculator](http://code.google.com/p/android-rpn-calculator/source/checkout)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Is there a way to get all the default apps (calculator, camera, browser, music player, etc.) in one place?

Comment: Well, I don't know for sure, but I doubt it. Just get them one by one. If my answer was useful to you, please accept it.